# Is it possible to clone data from external widget?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use a reviews widget from hypercomments, but I really stack on the idea of changing its design. The way it looks now is not looking good on my new template. So is there a possible way of cloning any data from widgets, I think jQuery can do that, but how? Any ideas/examples could help me a lot.

So for example the widget, after page loads, the html is in the following format:

```
<div id="widget">
  <div class="hc_comment">
    <div class="hc__message__txt">Hello world!</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

All I need is to load content from div with class "hc__message__txt" in my html block in div class "message".

```
<div class="reviews">
  <div class="message"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".message").text($(".hc__message__txt").text())
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Highly likely that the widget script won't have rendered the new html at `$(document).ready` stage

Comment: function changeText(){ $(".message").text($(".hc__message__txt").text()) } after rendered your widget load this function